# C# - Is it possible to make divide-by-zeros return a number, instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, math, error-handling, divide-by-zero

I have an expression that includes divisions, for which some of the denominators are sometimes zero. However, in those cases I would like that division to result in 1, instead of throwing an exception. Is there any straightforward way about doing this, or am I forced to do some if statements and changing the inputs to the expression to get this desired effect?

Comment: Why do you want to distort space and time like that?

Comment: what is your data-type? double doesn't throw here, IIRC - int will

Comment: Division with zero is nasty. I would surely check that before the division. Doubt that there is built-in functionality do do that for you, but it is an interesting question.

Comment: Can you simply not check to see if the Demominator is zero and return 1?

Comment: I want a function that makes Math.PI return "Delicious!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I must question the motives here, if you need to do it, make a function.

```
double SafeDiv(double num, double denom) {
   if(denom == 0) {
      return 1;
   }
   return num/denom;
}
```

Comment: +1 I cant see any more straight-forward and efficient solution than this. The templated solution by Michael Kjörling is nice too..

Comment: double never throws a divide-by-zero exception

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso: it returns ´infinity´, which is far from 1.

Comment: try with those number :var result= SafeDiv(5, -5);
I will return -1

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso: yes, as far as i know 5/-5 is exactly -1 :)

Comment: in this case it won't return 1. It would be better use the Double methods (IsNegativeInfinity/Double.IsPositiveInfinity/IsInfinity) to understand what is happening as showed also on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: The OP is asking for a return value of 1 if the denominator is *exactly 0*, not less than zero.

Comment: Yes, this might be the easiest way if C# doesn't allow redefinition of the / operator

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function for dividing.  Here's an extension sample idea:

```
public static float DivideBy(this float toBeDivided, float divideBy){
    try
    {
    return toBeDivided / divideBy;
    }
    catch(DivideByZeroException)
    {
    return 1.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a little goodie, the two arguments to your method are known as the dividend and the divisor respectively.

Comment: Also checking _divideBy_ for 0 first and return 1 would be way faster. Exceptions are really slow.

Comment: Why use a try catch? You know you'll get an exception when the divisor is zero, so just use an if statement.

Comment: Exceptions are slow, but if they happen rarely, a try/catch would generally be faster, as you are not checking a condition every time.  And I'd like to point out, this is just a sample idea; I really cannot fathom actually using this IRL.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using exception if they are just that - exceptions. The OP states that zeros are expected, so I doubt it counts as an exception..

Comment: I agree with you completely there. I just thought I'd mention it, so the questioner can read the thoughts on it too. Who know how experienced he is. Just in case.

Comment: @Jeremy, and comparing the value of a variable to a constant takes how long...? Seems like that's one of the cheapest operations you can perform, particularly if it does not involve any type instantiation or conversion under the hood.

Comment: Hah I'm not arguing the point, under the conditions implied, this is probably not the most performant option.  But it is clean, easy to understand, and it will work.  I think it's important to note that any time someone tries to divide by zero, it should be an exception... business rules aside, this is code that should not ever be written, much less used.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not possible to redefine the division operator for built in types, you need to implement your version of division in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
public T divide<T>(T dividend, T divisor) {
    return ((divisor == 0) ? (1) : (dividend / divisor));
}
```

or perhaps...

```
public T divide<T>(T dividend, T divisor) {
    try {
        return dividend / divisor;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Personally, if you know that the divisor may be 0 in some cases, I wouldn't consider that case "exceptional" and thus use the first approach (which can also, quite conveniently, be inlined manually if you are so inclined).

That said, I agree with what [Chris Marasti-Georg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501071/c-is-it-possible-to-make-divide-by-zeros-return-a-number-instead-of-throwing/7501174#7501174) wrote, and question the motives for doing this.

Comment: `==` won't work for your average T. And replacing it with Equals is a little shaky too when T is a float type.

Comment: You can always substitute a type that is appropriate for your particular case. I did write "something like this?"; I did not intend it to be used *exactly* as-is, particularly since (as you point out) equality is a bit shaky with floating-point types, and floating-point is probably closer to what the OP is after than integral math.

Answer (score 0):

No. If I understand your question, you would like to change the behavior of the divide operation and have it return 1 instead of throw. There is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the denominator first if not equal to zero perform the operation

```
public double ReturnValueFunction(int denominator, int numerator)
{
    try
    {
       if(denominator!=0)
       {
             return  numerator/ denominator; 

         /* or your code */
        }

  else
   {
            /*your code*/
        return someDecimalnumber;
   }
}
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If either divider or divisor are double and divisor is 0 (or 0.0) result is positive or negative infinity. It will pass through all subsequent operations without throwing, and instead returning ±Infinity or NaN, depending on the other operand. Later you can check if final value is something meaningful.

If it is for some reason necessary to return 1 when dividing by zero, then you have several options:

- Custom generic function
- Custom type with overloaded operators
- Check if divisor is 0 before the division

This is not something that is usually done, as far as I know, so you might rethink why would you do that..

Comment: 0/5 = 0, 5/0 = PositiveInfinity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this

```
    double res = a / (b == 0 ? a : b);
```